# toggle replies, show and hide replies. And by default they should be hidden

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, angular, angular2-template

```js
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-module1-7',
  templateUrl: './module1-7.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./module1-7.component.scss']
})

export class Module17Component implements OnInit {
  public replyBox = false;
  public txtcomment : string
  public txtcommentSub : string
  public show:boolean = false;
  public prevClicked:number = -1;jsonObj={};
  public counter:Number; 
  public subcomments = false;

  constructor() { 
    this.replyBox =false;
  }
  heroes = [{'comment':'first comment','show':false,'type':'comment'}, {'comment':'second comment','show':false,'type':'comment'},{'comment' :'third comment','show':false,'type':'comment'},{'comment':'fourth comment','show':false,'type':'comment'},{'comment':'fifth comment','show':false,'type':'comment'},{'comment':'sixth comment','show':false,'type':'comment'}];
  addHero(newHero,val,index) {
    // console.log(newHero)
    if(val == 0){
      if (newHero) {
        this.jsonObj['comment']=newHero
        this.jsonObj['show']= false;
        this.heroes.unshift(
        {
          "comment":newHero,
          "show":false,
          "type":"comment"
        });
        this.txtcomment = '';
        console.log('new val', this.heroes)
      }
    }
    else{
      newHero = newHero.replace(/"/g, "'");
      newHero = newHero.replace(/(?:\r\n|\r|\n)/g, ' ');
      var str = '{"comment":"'+newHero+'","show":false,"type":"reply"}';
      console.log(str)
      this.heroes.splice(index+1,0,JSON.parse(str))
      this.txtcommentSub= '';
      this.replyBox = false;
      console.log(this.heroes)
    }
  }
  subComment(i){
    this.replyBox = true;
    if(this.heroes[this.prevClicked] && this.prevClicked != i) {
        this.heroes[this.prevClicked].show = false;
      }
      this.heroes[i].show = !this.heroes[i].show;
      this.prevClicked = i;
  }
  ngOnInit() {
    this.replyBox =false;
    this.counter = 3;
  }
  showMore(){
    this.counter = Number(this.counter) + 3;
  }
  less(){
    this.counter = Number(this.counter) - 3;
  }  
}
```

```css
.blog-comment::before,
.blog-comment::after,
.blog-comment-form::before,
.blog-comment-form::after {
    content: "";
    display: table;
    clear: both;
}

.blog-comment {
    // padding-left: 15%;
    padding-right: 15%;
}

.blog-comment ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
}

.blog-comment .post-comments {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 85px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #6b6e80;
    position: relative;
}

.post-comments-child {
    border: 1px solid #eee;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 85px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    background: #fff;
    color: #6b6e80;
    position: relative;
}

.txtarea {
    border-radius: 4px !important;
}

.post-comments-text {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-left: 66px;
    margin-right: -18px;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    position: relative;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -o-border-radius: 4px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    position: relative;
}

.blog-comment .meta {
    font-size: 13px;
    color: #aaaaaa;
    padding-bottom: 8px;
    margin-bottom: 10px !important;
    border-bottom: 1px solid #eee;
}

.blog-comment ul.comments ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin-left: 85px;
}

.blog-comment-form {
    padding-left: 15%;
    padding-right: 15%;
    padding-top: 40px;
}

.blog-comment h3,
.blog-comment-form h3 {
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    font-size: 26px;
    line-height: 30px;
    font-weight: 800;
}

.post-comments:after {
    content: ' ';
    position: absolute;
    width: 0;
    height: 0;
    left: auto;
    right: -20px;
    top: 9px;
    bottom: auto;
    border: 12px solid;
    border-color: #fff transparent transparent #fff;
}

.links {
    margin-right: 5px;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
            <div class="blog-comment">
                <h6 class="text-success">Discussion Name</h6>
                <hr/>
                <div class="mainCommentTextbox">
                    <div class="post-comments-text form-group">
                        <textarea class="form-control txtarea" id="exampleTextarea" placeholder="Enter your comment here" rows="3" #newHero (keyup.enter)="addHero(newHero.value,0)" [(ngModel)]="txtcomment"></textarea>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <ul class="comments" *ngFor="let hero of heroes; let i= index">
                    <li class="clearfix" id={{i}} *ngIf="hero.type=='comment' && i  < counter">
                        <div class="post-comments">
                            <p class="meta">Amrut Jadhav <a>Dec 18, 2014</a> : <i class="pull-right"><a (click)="subComment(i)"><small>Reply</small></a></i></p>
                            <p>
                                {{hero.comment}}
                            </p>
                            <p class="meta-footer"><a (click)="subcomments=!subcomments"><i class="pull-right fa " [class.fa-plus]="subcomments==false" [class.fa-minus]="subcomments==true" aria-hidden="true"></i></a></p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="" id="" *ngIf="hero.show">
                            <div class="post-comments-text form-group" *ngIf="replyBox">
                                <textarea class="form-control txtarea" id="exampleTextarea" rows="3" #newHero (keyup.enter)="addHero(newHero.value,1,i)" [(ngModel)]="txtcommentSub"></textarea>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="clearfix" id={{i}} *ngIf="hero.type=='reply'">
                        <div class="post-comments-child" style="margin-left:15%">
                            <p class="meta">Amrut Jadhav <a>Dec 18, 2014</a></p>
                            <p>
                                {{hero.comment}}
                            </p>
                        </div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <div class="text-center">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary links" *ngIf="counter < heroes.length" (click)="showMore()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-down" aria-hidden="true"></i> show more</button>
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary links" *ngIf="counter > 3" (click)="less()"><i class="fa fa-arrow-up" aria-hidden="true"></i> less</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

I am designing own commenting system that little bit works fine issue is i want to hide replies by default & when i click on (+,-) icon it should show & hide.
So to be as clear as possible, if there's comment A,and then under that comment A there are some replies available by default they should hidden, & when click (+) icon all replies need to be shown & plus icon change to (-). & again when i click on (-) icon all replies need to be hide & icon should change to (+). but replies of specific comment display on its button click. image here

[image]

Comment: So you want something like an accordion styled comment box?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [hide/show specific child element of main element on click event](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47449155/hide-show-specific-child-element-of-main-element-on-click-event)

Comment: yes but i want to show & hide specific comments reply

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps.Bootstrap classes have been used.Add all imports to use this method. Run the snippet.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  
<style>

  #minus{
  display:inline;
  }
  .collapsed #minus{
  
  display:none;
  
  }
  #plus{
  
  display:none;
  
  }
  .collapsed #plus{
  
  display:inline;
  
  }
  
  
  </style>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
<div class="row" style="margin:100px auto;">
  <ul class="list-group">
  <li class="list-group-item" style="text-align:center">
  Toggle List
  </li>
  <li class="list-group-item">
  <button type="button" class="btn btn-info collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#demo"><span id="plus">+</span><span id="minus">-</span></button>
  <div id="demo" class="collapse">
    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit,
    sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam,
    quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  </div>
  </li>
  
  
  </ul>
  </div>
  
</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You could use many methods, I used Bootstrap because it handles a lot of the load (You can use jquery to simulate the same).